# Unable to get user ID for paid users on GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am facing the problem of not getting the user_id in GA4 reports and explorations for paid users.

The page path for these users is a popup path for our payment processor or a FlutterViewController for our mobile apps. We want to find which page actually made that user who paid, a new user.

We get page paths with no. of new users and on viewing the user segment, we get the user_id with many of them.

But when we track no. of purchases, the page paths are the popup path or FlutterViewController and it shows as if almost all of them were not new users with a few returning users too. But as we had started sending user_id from all the pages of our website since only a week back, we are not seeing many of the old users' user_ids. But we should see it for the last week ones - at least for the users who paid after that that we are not able to see.

What is the way to get their (paid users) user_ids and the page path that made them the new user?

I tried using page path as dimension and new users, returning users and total purchasers as metrics.

I did not get the same person as a new user as well as the purchaser for a particular path. All the paths for purchasers were either popup or FlutterViewController.

When I tried first source for purchasers, I got our payment processor's URL instead of the page where they first met our pages.

We expect that they get the user IDs and start showing the proper page source.

Thanks and Regards,
Shubham